# Selecting dropdown in WebDriverJs

Tags: javascript, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have a dropdown box that I would like to select a value using WebDriverJS. I've looked at the user guide below and could not find out how to do it

> https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs

I even try a few things that was documented for Java version like this:

```
webdriver.Select(driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id("vote"))).selectByValue("5")
```

And it just simply says that "Select" does not exist.

I went through the source and still cannot find anything that I can use.

Answer (score 15):

You don't need two clicks to select an option, just click on the option directly. Something like,

```
driver.findElement(wd.By.css('#month>option[title="November"]')).click();
```

Comment: is title an attribute? or name?

Comment: title is an attribute

Answer (score 10):

I shared a function to select a drop down item by it's text [here](https://coderwall.com/p/tjx5zg).

The code:

```
function selectOption(selector, item){
    var selectList, desiredOption;

    selectList = this.findElement(selector);
    selectList.click();

    selectList.findElements(protractor.By.tagName('option'))
        .then(function findMatchingOption(options){
            options.some(function(option){
                option.getText().then(function doesOptionMatch(text){
                    if (item === text){
                        desiredOption = option;
                        return true;
                    }
                });
            });
        })
        .then(function clickOption(){
            if (desiredOption){
                desiredOption.click();
            }
        });
}
```

use with:

```
driver.selectOption = selectOption.bind(driver);
driver.selectOption(webdriver.By.id('my-dropdown'), 'My Value');
```

Comment: Good thing about this solution, is that it search by text, not by option number.

Comment: Paul Roub answer below is fair simpler, works perfectly and has same effect.

driver.findElement({id: 'myDropDown'}).sendKeys('name_of_option');

Answer (score 5):

```js
driver.findElement({id: 'myDropDown'});// select dropdown element you wish to select
driver.sleep(1000);//not necessary
driver.findElement({id: 'myDropDown'}).sendKeys('name_of_option');//sending keys automatically fills dropdown with desired option
```

Comment: This worked for me, selecting the dropdown then sending keys

Answer (score 3):

I am using [webdriverjs](https://github.com/camme/webdriverjs) and want to select the option by index, so did:

```
driver.click('#my_select_box').click('#my_select_box option:nth-child(3)')
```

Answer (score 2):

This should achieved by

```
selectElem = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id("vote"))
selectElem.click()
selectElem.findElement(webdriver.By.css("option[value='5']")).click()
```

Comment: When dealing with asynchronous code (Promises and all) this will fail.

Comment: This will fail with async code. Can you clean it up with chained processing

Answer (score 2):

Sending keys to the dropdown element would be sufficient in this case, like;

```
driver.findElement(by.id('vote')).sendKeys('5');
```

When there is a space in the display text, webdriver needs to focus more so just adding click functions would solve it;

```
var ddlElement = driver.findElement(by.id('vote'));
ddlElement.click();
ddlElement.sendKeys('5');
ddlElement.click();
```

Answer (score 1):

Certain browsers were being very difficult with dropdowns.  I got some ideas and pieced together a java method using JS injection that might work for some of you who come across this.  Yes, the issues are being fixed over time, but this is useful for those who are tasked with certifying older browsers.
I hope this helps, because this can be very frustrating!

```
public void getJSDropdown(String dropDown, String elementID)throws Exception{

     JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
     String dropdownScript = "var select = window.document.getElementById('" + 
             dropDown +
             "'); for(var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++){if(select.options[i].text == '" +
             elementID +
             "'){ select.options[i].selected = true; } }";

     Thread.sleep(2000);
     executor.executeScript(dropdownScript);
     Thread.sleep(2000);

     String clickScript = "if ("+"\"createEvent\""+" in document) {var evt = document.createEvent("+"\"HTMLEvents\""+");     evt.initEvent("+"\"change\""+", false, true); " + dropDown + ".dispatchEvent(evt); } else " + dropDown + ".fireEvent("+"\"onchange\""+");";

     executor.executeScript(clickScript);

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`driver.click('//*[@id="vote"]/option[3]')`

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22159563/227578

Answer (score 0):

This will work for me (coffeescript)

```
selectList.findElements(By.tagName("option")) =
.then (options) ->
    len = options.length         #getting number of options in the select
    driver.wait =>               #verify all promises finished
        for option in options
            option.getText()
            .then (text) =>
                console.log(len)
                len -= 1
                console.log(text)
                if len is 0
                    true
    , 10000
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using the following with ES6:

```
 let select = driver.findElement(By.css("select"));
 let options = select.findElements(By.css("option"));
 options.then(values => {
     return Promise.all(values.map(el => el.getText())).then(optTexts => {
         return values[optTexts.indexOf('Some option text')].click();
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

use xpath like that

```
await driver.findElement(By.xpath('//[@id="newEventOffices"]/option[3]')).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the select element and click on it to display the dropdown

`driver.findElement(//div//select[@id="elementId"]).click();`

Then select from the options and click on it. I think selecting by xpath will really work better here.

`driver.findElement(By.xpath('//div//select[@id="elementId"]//option[optionIndex]')).click();`

Answer (score 0):

I get same problem, and above solutions not working in my typeScript case

But I still find a solution:

```
await driver.findElement(By.id("ELEMENT_ID")).sendKeys("SOME_VALUE");
```

Due to driver will return a promise when get a **selector element**

So add **await** to do the next things

Answer (score -1):

The following code defines the available selectors in WebDriverJS:

```
webdriver.Locator.Strategy = {
  'className': webdriver.Locator.factory_('class name'),
  'class name': webdriver.Locator.factory_('class name'),
  'css': webdriver.Locator.factory_('css selector'),
  'id': webdriver.Locator.factory_('id'),
  'js': webdriver.Locator.factory_('js'),
  'linkText': webdriver.Locator.factory_('link text'),
  'link text': webdriver.Locator.factory_('link text'),
  'name': webdriver.Locator.factory_('name'),
  'partialLinkText': webdriver.Locator.factory_('partial link text'),
  'partial link text': webdriver.Locator.factory_('partial link text'),
  'tagName': webdriver.Locator.factory_('tag name'),
  'tag name': webdriver.Locator.factory_('tag name'),
  'xpath': webdriver.Locator.factory_('xpath')
};

goog.exportSymbol('By', webdriver.Locator.Strategy);
```

Source: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/javascript/webdriver/locators.js

Answer (score -1):

This is not actually clicking the option, but it does in fact select it.

1. Find **select** element
2. Click **select** element
3. Type **option** text into select element using sendKeys()
4. Click **select** element

Comment: This fails on different browsers, at leas I tried mac chrome, windows FF and it failed ):

Comment: This will not work!. Java approach will not suffice here

Comment: Code samples please?