# With webdriver.js, how to get the selected option of a <select>?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Plenty of answers for java and C#, but I can't find how to do it in javascript. Seems the API are different...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yeah it is possible. Lets say we have the following select element:

```
<select name="test" id="select">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

You get the current selected option by using getValue and you can change the selection by using click. Here is an simple example:

```
var webdriverjs = require('webdriverjs'),
    client      = webdriverjs.remote({desiredCapabilities:{browserName:'phantomjs'}}).init();

client
    .url('http://localhost:8080')
    .getValue('#select',function(err,val){
        console.log(val); // will output "1"
    })
    .click('//*[@id="select"]/option[3]')
    .getValue('#select',function(err,val){
        console.log(val); // will output "3"
    })
    .end();
```

Hope that helps.

cheers

Comment: +1 But this is framework specific, however the idea is correct and helped me go in the right direction. For those interested in pure WebDriver solution, check out my answer.

Answer (score 3):

For those who are just looking for pure WebDriverJS solution and not any framework specific like webdriver.io or protractor, here is the code,

```
var element = driver.findElement(wd.By.id('mySelect'));
element.getAttribute('value').then(function(selected) {
   if(selected === 'the one I expected') {
       done();
   } 
   else {
     done(new Error('something went wrong');
   }
});
```

Comment: var SelectedValue=element.getAttribute('value').then(function(selected) { return selected;});

Answer (score 2):

If you want the option element, use the return value of `then` callback:

```
driver.findElement(By.css('select[name=eventTypes]'))
  .then((select) => {
    return select.getAttribute('value').then((value) => {
      return {select: select, value: value};
    });
  })
  .then((data) => {
    return data.select.findElement(By.css('option[value="'+data.value+'"]'));
  })
  .then((option) => {
    //do something.
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have this in your html for an example

```
<select name="test" id="myId">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

You can select for a example option 3 like this

```
var driver = new firefox.Driver();
driver.findElement(By.css('#myId>option:nth-child(2)')).click();
```

Works for me and I am using selenium-webdriver with JavaScript

Comment: Please add an explanation to this so others can understand why it works. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for this! I tried a whole bunch of other ways to do this, but this was the only one that actually worked.

Answer (score 0):

Although the question has been posted for 7 years, I would like to share my answer that works now. You can get the selected option/value by

```
let select_value =  await driver.findElement(By.css('select')).getAttribute('value')
```

Comment: You may want to point out this is essentially the same as the answer posted by the original poster.  This answer is using await, whereas the original poster is using a promise continuation.

Answer (score 0):

I did using this

```
element=await driver.findElement(By.name("quantity")); // here you have to select your element suppose i am using get element by name


// below will help you to get selected value from select option
var SelectedValue=element.getAttribute('value').then(function(selected) { return selected;});
```