# JavsScript can not click on element "option"

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

Below is the HTML code for the element I want to click:

```
<select id = "per-page-xxxxxxxx" //xxxxxxx is a dynamic string
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
    <option value="100">100</option>
</select>
```

It is basically a dropdown list that allow you to choose how many items to be displayed on current page.

My code to click `<option value="100">100</option>` is:

```
var dropdownListXpath = "//select[starts-with(@id,'per-page-')]";
var PublicationPerPageOptionXpath = "//select[starts-with(@id,'per-page-')]/option[@value='100']";
var dropdownList;
var PublicationPerPageOption;

aqUtils.Delay(500);
try {
    dropdownList = PageObj.EvaluateXpath(dropdownListXpath);
    dropdownList[0].Click();
    aqUtils.Delay(500);
    PublicationPerPageOption = PageObj.EvaluateXpath(PublicationPerPageOptionXpath);
    PublicationPerPageOption[0].Click();
}
catch(err) {
    Log.Message("Can not find options to show 100 publications per page.");
}
```

The result:

- Dropdown list is clicked and expanded, then nothing happens afterwards, e.g. option 100 is not clicked

Can anyone please provide any help?

Comment: Are you using some framework? Indepentend from that question: try a change-event listener on the select element instead a click event.

Comment: @user6849557, I am using testComplete. I will look into change-event listener, thanks

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15859143/selecting-dropdown-in-webdriverjs

Comment: thank you, will do. @MikeJRamsey56