# Selenium Webdriver can not locate element by xPath

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using two different ways to access a web element with Selenium webdriver **(JavaScript)**.

The first way uses a number indicating third `div` element in the parent `div`. The code is like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='sld-layer-container']/div/div/ul/li[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/select/option[2]")).click();
```

This code doesn't work. It returns error: `ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated`

The second way uses class to identify the specific `div` in parent `div`. Code is like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='sld-layer-container']/div/div/ul/li[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[@class = 'col-md-5']/select/option[2]")).click();
```

As you can see, the only difference is the identifier of last div element in xPath string. They should indicate the same thing. Magically the second one works but not the first one.

Here is a screenshot of css elements. The `div` highlighted is what I am trying to locate.[image]

Can anyone help me with this?

Update 1:

As @Mahipal and @iamkenos required, I expended the `div` and now it is showing `select` and `option`. I thought the issue was only caused by not being able to locate the `div` but it seems not. Please help further.
[image]

Comment: You want to select an option from drop-down or just reach to the `div`. As, after looking at your xpath, it seems you are trying to select an option from drop-down. If this is the case, could you expand the div tag, so that, html for the `select` control can be seen?

Comment: Looking at your code, you're trying to click `option[2]` of a certain `select` dropdown. If this is the case, there are other ways to do it. Also, I would suggest not to rely so much on index-based xpath locators as the html design may change frequently specially during development phase. As Mahipal suggested, please expand the highlighted div so we can help you further. PS. Please provide the actual snippet, not the screenshot.

Comment: Can you provide us complete DOM

Comment: Thank you! I have uploaded the expended div in update 1. Please help. @iamkenos

Comment: Thank you! I have uploaded the expended div in update 1. Please help. @Mahipal

Comment: I didn't notice that you were using WebDriverJS. I wont be able to help you there. However, you may find this xpath helpful: `//div[@id='sld-layer-container']//div[@id='featureClassList']//select[contains(@data-ng-model,'layer.symbologyName')]`. Also, try checking the answers from this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15859143/selecting-dropdown-in-webdriverjs

Answer (score 1):

you can try as below:

```
 Select select = new Select (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='sld-layer-container']/div/div/ul/li[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/select")));

 select.selectByVisibleText("PROJECT_VALUE");
```

Comment: I am using javascript. Does it have select object?

Comment: I used this code and it complained no selectByVisibleText exist. `let select = this.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='sld-layer-container']/div/div/ul/li[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/select"));
        select.selectByVisibleText("PROJ_TYPE");`

Comment: As you have pasted the new screen shot you can see it has The Select object.

Comment: Sorry I confused you. What I meant is if selenium web driver for Javascript the language itself has Select object concept. If it does, how can I import it. I tried `webdriver.Select` but it doesn't work.

Comment: try something like `((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.getElementById('id').selectedIndex = '" + index + "';)`

Comment: or check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38239278/how-to-select-a-value-from-drop-down-using-selenium

Answer (score -1):

you can try with below xpath as well...

```
//div[@id='featureClassList']//div[@class='col-md-5']
```

Comment: You are trying to start with lower level divs. Unfortunately, featureClassList and 'col-md-5' are not identical. Even it works, it's not answering my question.

Comment: Above Kushal's Select object is the best one to be used for 'Select' html tag dropdown. Only thing is, when you use Absolute Xpaths, it wont work all time. You need to find the Relative xpath i.e. Lower level divs as you mean. The relative xpath:

   
     '//div[@id='featureClassList']//select//option[text()='PROJECT_VALUE']'    


     "//div[@id='featureClassList']" is very important to find the respective parent of Select object.

Comment: Thank you! It explained my issue. As you can see, the xpath I used started from `//div[@id='sld-layer-container']`. I think this is the lowest identical item I can find in this case. If I still want to start with this object, what's the difference between absolute path and relative path?

Comment: Another question, can I use index number in a relative path?

Comment: Absolute xpaths include path from all the Super Parents of an Element. 
Like this: "//div[@id='sld-layer-container']/div/div/ul/li[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/select", where Select is the element you want to identify and before div's are Parent.
While Relative xpath involves in framing xpath using any of the elements attribute(ex. id's, class, texts, labels etc). 
If still the elements with identical attributes found, we go for its next parent element attributes.

Comment: In my xpath, "option[text()='PROJE‌​CT_VALUE']" is enough to identify the element. 
But, what if, front end dev's includes some other 'option' tag in some other place with same text, so to ensure a single and right element, we are using its parent attributes i.e. "//div[@id='featureClassList']".

Comment: I wont recommend indexing. If you are sure that, no other element will be newly installed, then, you may go for indexing, like option[2].